# Approximate values of amount modifiers

Tags: numbers, modifiers

This is an area of English that I consistently have trouble with. Consider the following sentences.

1. I have a couple of books on my desk.
2. I have a bunch of books on my desk.
3. I have a number of books on my desk.
4. I have a few books on my desk.
5. I have several books on my desk.
6. I have many books on my desk.

How many books, give or take, do I have on my desk in each case?

[digression: one example of how I tend to get these wrong is the following: not long ago, my wife (native speaker of American English) and me were out with a few friends from out of town. At one point I said "[famous landmark] is only two hundred meters from here", to which my wife replied "no, it's more like a a couple hundred meters".]

Comment: @Fumble yes, although this does have more options than just "*a few*" and "*a couple.*"

Comment: @Tim: Several of the answers on the original specifically mention ***several***. Personally I think this type of question is fairly pointless here on ELU - for native speakers it's all a matter of opinion, and learners who don't yet *have* an opinion should be addressing such issues on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, it is quite opinion based, I tried to give the most factual, but even *few* I can't decide on myself.

Comment: In each case you have "some" books on your desk.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have a couple of books on my desk.

   2, no arguments. A couple is 2. NB: If the person saying it is *a couple* is wrong (maybe distance), it is unlikely to be more than 4 or 5 of that item / unit. [Kudos @Bye](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193813/approximate-values-of-amount-modifiers/193817#comment405935_193817)

   > two people or things of the same sort considered together.
   >   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20a%20couple)
2. I have a bunch of books on my desk.

   Same as a number - undefined:

   > a number of things, typically of the same kind, growing or fastened together.
   >   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20a%20bunch)
3. I have a number of books on my desk.

   Not defined, anywhere from 1 to 1000000...

   > a quantity or amount
   >   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20a%20few)
4. I have a few books on my desk.

   I go for 3 or 4

   > a small number of.
   >   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20a%20few).
5. I have several books on my desk.

   Same as above in my opinion - 3 or 4

   > more than two but not many.
   >   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20several)
6. I have many books on my desk.

   A lot, more than 10 I would say - but it depends on what you are referring - I have many pets could be 5+, there are many stars in the sky is 1,000,000,000+

   > a large number of.
   >   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20many).

Comment: In common, everyday use, *a couple of* (or, more properly, *a coupla*) is exactly two... but certainly no more than a half-dozen or so at most if it turns out not to have been two.

Comment: Non-two uses of *a couple* also include *but I've only had a couple of drinks, Constable* and *I'll just be a couple of minutes*. (Not nit-picking; just being thorough. It's not so much a grammatical or vocabulary issue as a divorce from some aspects of reality.)

Comment: I wont include them because the literal "translation" of couple is 2, and that is people manipulating the truth - they could equally say 2 and it would be a lie as well!

Answer (score 0):

This is only personal opinion.

If I had two or three books on the desk then I would use either (1) or (3) or (4) or (5).

> (1) I have a couple of books on my desk.
>     (3) I have a number of books on my desk.
>     (4) I have a few books on my desk.
>     (5) I have several books on my desk.

If I had four through nine books on the desk then I would use (3).

> (3) I have a number of books on my desk.

If I had more than nine books on the desk then I would use (6).

> (6) I have many books on my desk.

I would not use (2) with *bunch.*

Comment: This is quite confusing as you have to keep scrolling back up to reference it.

Comment: @Tim I fixed it,